# How do I have signed fields in Django?

Tags: python, mysql, database, django

```
class MyTable(models.Model):
    lat = models.FloatField(blank=True)
    long = models.FloatField(blank=True)
```

How do I make them signed? Able to accept negative .

Comment: You seem a tad confused. "Unsigned" means that they *can't* accept negative values.

Comment: FloatField *can* accept signed numbers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`FloatField` can accept floating point numbers, negatives included.

If you need positive-only integers, there's [PositiveIntegerField](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#positiveintegerfield). Positive-only floats are a much rarer need, so I don't think they're natively supported - but you can, of course, implement this restriction programatically.